# Unable to run RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 from a VMware image.

I am trying to start the RabbitMQ server. I have followed the instructions from [RabbitMQ website](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html) but with no luck.

When I type the command

```
sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start --force
```

I get the message:

> * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server

And that's it. It is stuck there and does not progress.
I have no idea where to go from here and what to check as I am not that good in Linux just yet.